# Can I access My Custom .NET Class from PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, powershell

I have a couple of questions and doubts to regarding PowerShell and .NET Classes.

I am trying to write a class 'foo' that will call Rest web service and perform some tasks.  If I deploy the class in GAC then can I call it from PowerShell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
ADD-TYPE -AssemblyName myassemblyname
```

or

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("myassemblyname")
```

to access method/properties of your assembly you can do this:

```
[myassemblyname]::mymethod()
[myassemblyname]::myproperty
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load your assembly with the `Add-Type` cmdlet or with System.Reflection.Assembly class and then you can use the `New-Object` cmdlet to create objects from your assembly classes.

Comment: And this way I can access all the methods of that object in PowerShell and automate things.  Cool.

Comment: yes, take a look at the code examples of Add-Type, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315241.aspx