# Windows Task Scheduler vs Windows Service for .Net application

Tags: c#, powershell, ftp, windows-services, windows-task-scheduler

I know variations of this topic have already been asked, but here's my situation:

I have about 30 FTP interface applications. Each interface has their own requirements and configuration, but basically it downloads files from a source server – sometimes daily, sometimes every minute (some, possibly even scheduled in the seconds)

For my initial development, I wrote a C# class library that does all FTP work. This application (be it a console app or windows service) will most likely be run under Windows Server 2012.

Now comes the next piece and I’m trying to decide between:

> 1)    Writing a console app (or a powershell script?) that takes command
>   line inputs plus a configuration file for each interface. I would
>   schedule this using Windows Task Scheduler. For deployment of these
>   interfaces, I could create a batch file that uses the “schtasks.exe”
>   to create and configure the task. One task for each interface.  Sounds
>   easy peasy…

OR

> 2)    Write a windows services application… but here, I am confused. Do I
>   create and install a service for each one of my interfaces? (i.e. only
>   thing different might be the config file). Or, do I create a a main
>   service that spawns off threads for each interface defined in a single
>   config file?
>
> If  I did this as a single service, how do I manage the
>   maintenance/deployment of this? If I stop the service, would it not
>   affect all the interfaces?    And how do I perform the actual
>   scheduling? I’ve read the suggestion is to use Quartz.Net scheduler or
>   just .Net Timers.

-*-*-

Some additional thoughts:
Here are some readings on StackOverflow which brings up these topics/concerns:

[windows service vs scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task)
[Scheduled console app vs Windows service? When is it appropriate to use each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507674/scheduled-console-app-vs-windows-service-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-each)

Task Scheduler Concerns

- List item
- May need to be logged in? (I’ve read this is not true)
- Issues on machine admin password change (I’ve read this is not true)
- Issues with running in high-authority accounts (NetworkService, LocalSystem, or a User)
- Issue with multiple processes / long running transactions 
  This would be really bad for me, for example, if two processes tried to download (and delete) the same source FTP file.
- Experience of many is that this is not as stable/reliable as Windows Services, especially on earlier operating systems pre Windows7
- Less infrastructure support (e.g. failure policies for retry, monitoring, etc.)
- Concerns when scheduling in the seconds…

Windows Service Concerns

- List item
- Potential issues with Timers
- More complicated

Console App + Scheduled Task Concerns

- List item
- Can’t run in background – so hosting server will have command prompts launching
  This is a serious problem. If I have 30 FTP Interfaces and each is scheduled to run every minute/hour, that’s a lot of windows!!!
- How do I get around this? Use PowerShell scripts instead?

Looking forward to some feedback, and sample code/scripts, if relevant also highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _full real world_ sample (C# library for FTP) with `good patterns and practices` using ***task scheduler, windows service or quartz*** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access your c# class in powershell using 
Either `add-type` or `[System.Reflection.Assembly]` - check out this SO post for examples - [Can I access My Custom .NET Class from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212459/can-i-access-my-custom-net-class-from-powershell)

You could do it all in powershell, using `start-job` and the like, but then your controlling script will need a lot of effort.

I'd be tempted to use Powershell' inbuilt (in version 3) cmdlets for creating/modifying scheduled jobs in task scheduler and custom triggers - http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx

Have it schedule jobs that are running .ps1 powershell scripts, one for each transfer or group of related transfers e.g. `Monthly_Payroll_xfer.ps1`, `Weekly_Expenses_xfer.ps1` with logic relevant to that transfer, email alerts on success/failure etc.

The only thing that doesn't solve is same file/destination being processed at the same time  but you could potentially have the individual scripts check at start if they are running already - see the accepted answer to this post - [Assure only 1 instance of PowerShell Script is Running at any given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969662/assure-only-1-instance-of-powershell-script-is-running-at-any-given-time)

As for windows prompts, you can run a scheduled task as a user that won't be logged on, and you won't see the powershell command windows as they will be on a different console - be sure not to set `-noexit` switch of powershell.exe so they do go away when finished.

Had to do this at work for a tool that only runs as GUI, not as a service, and can't be frigged with `srvany` etc - we setup a scheduled task that runs (at startup) as a service account and runs a powershell script that runs the GUI.exe

We then use powershell scripts to `stop-process` to kill it, disable/enable the task (like disabling/enabling a service) and one to run the task.

It's a cludge but it works.

Apologies I haven't given much in the way of code examples, doing this on my phone but may give you ideas.

You can also do it all in c# - we have an in-house developed application with SQL back-end that does exactly what you're trying to achieve, very successfully, multi-threaded with very high volumes being chucked at it..

However, my employers' Intellectual Property and other policies prevent me sharing any more about it than that :-(